# Mule JUnit Test on Exception Stack

Tags: java, junit, mule, junit4, mule-studio

I am trying to create a JUnit test on a Mule Flow that I created where we test if a custom exception is thrown when a file is not provided.

Currently I am manually triggering the Mule service by using Java to drop files into the listening directory to trigger the file-endpoint that kicks off the Flow.  I then evaluate the output files to see if the flow is working appropriately.  Is there a way to do the same thing, but where a JUnit test component can listen to the Mule service and capture the exception stack payload and assert the actual and expected error message?

To give more of an abstract idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Test
public void testValidExceptionThrown () throws Exception {
    MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();

    dropInputFileIntoPlace("control_000001.dat","input/control_000001.dat");

    MuleEventContext eventContext = getTestEventContext(client);
    MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
    String strActualExceptionMessage = message.getExceptionPayload().getMessage();
    String strExpectedMessage = "Custom Exception";

    assertEquals("the exception message thrown matches the expected exception message", strExpectedMessage, strActualExceptionMessage);
}
```

Is there a way for me to capture the eventContext of when I trigger the Mule flow manually with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MuleClient` to send file to your endpoint like this, instead of manually dropping the file

```
muleClient.dispatch("file://D:/test_docs/in", inputFileName, null);
```

**EDIT:**

Once you've dispatched the file, if your flow writes to a `file:outbound-endpoint` in normal course or also in error case, you could request the file like this:

```
MuleMessage result = client.request("file://D:/test_docs/out/error", 5000);
```

Remember to **use** `Thread.sleep` after `client.dispatch()` method else Mule will not wait for the flow to process and request file as soon after dispatch.

Comment: Since, dispatch is "one-way", if I need to evaluate the message payload, how would I request for it to evaluate the result of dispatching the file?

Comment: Is there a way to use the client.request to retrieve a listener to capture when an exception is thrown in Mule application?

Comment: I know for synchronous endpoints like `http` but not `file` which is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Use [MUnit](https://github.com/mulesoft/munit), you can use it from JUnit, Mule config files, make assertions, mock message processors, etc.